# Mobx return empty Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, mobx, mobx-react

I would like to use **Mobx** in React project (with Meteor) and create global Notification store with `mobx-react`.

I try to init the module, but I don't know why it returns an empty object :

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class NotificationStore {
  @observable notifications = ['test', 'new notification'];
}

var store = window.store = new NotificationStore;

export default store;
```

And in my App.js :

```
import store from '../../components/NotificationStore';

console.log(store); // return Object { }
```

Anyone knows why my object is empty ?

Thank you community !

Comment: That's very odd. It works [**for me**](http://jsbin.com/cenibayuyi/1/edit?js,console,output). Maybe you overwrite `window.store` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Hi ! In your example, the object in empty too, nop ?

Comment: Write `store.notifications.toJS()` and you will see the values.

Comment: Haw yes, it work with `store.notifications.toJS()`, thank you :) Maybe the problem is because it's on MeteorJS env .. thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is working as intended. Try to write `store.notifications.toJS()` in [**this console**](http://jsbin.com/cenibayuyi/1/edit?js,console,output) to see your array. Keep in mind that a MobX-array is not a real JavaScript array, so you might have to use `toJS` when logging or passing values to external libraries for it to work properly.